# Reassigning stdout gives different behavior with one character and multiple characters

Tags: c

I just noticed a weird behavior in a very simple C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    stdout = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    printf("X"); /* This prints X to the terminal */
    printf("YZ"); /* This writes YZ to the file out.txt */
    return 0;
}
```

Why does printing a one character string output it to the terminal/console, and printing two character string write to `stdout`(in this case, out.txt)?

I am using GCC version 5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: i tried the code and experienced the same issue, if you change first print to printf("XY") it works fine tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign `stdout`, following the C89 specification :

> 116. The primary use of the freopen function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout), as those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value returned by the fopen function may be assigned.

So, you should use `freopen()`. You can discard the assignment (as said in the standard you can't assign standard text streams) and simply do `freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);`.

Comment: I will add that the compiler optimize the call by `putchar` and it may use file descriptor `1` instead of `stdout`. That why the behavior is different with one or two characters.

Comment: Thanks, @Stargateur that clears it up very well for me. I should have probably tried using gdb or strace and looked harder. Thanks again.